# Xaringan: image resize option does not work for me

Tags: r-markdown, xaringan

For some reason, `![:scale 50%](image.jpg)` does not work for me.
Any solution to fix this?

My yaml heading is the following:

```
---
title: "Econ"
subtitle: "Orientation and Lecture 1"
author: "Teacher"
institute: "University"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: [default, metropolis, metropolis-fonts, "styles.css"]
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: arta
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
      
---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scale an image in xaringan slides (in R-markdown), a safe option is using `knitr::include_graphics` along with chunk options.

````
```{r echo=FALSE, out.width="50%"}
knitr::include_graphics("test_animal.jpg")
```
````

**Update**

If you want to fill the entire slide with an image you can use `background-image` and `background-size` option in xaringan slides to do that.

```
---
title: "Econ"
subtitle: "Lecture 1"
author: "Instructor"
institute: "College"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: [default, metropolis, metropolis-fonts, "styles.css"]
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: arta
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
    
---

---
background-image: url(test_animal.jpg)
background-size: cover
```

Comment: thanks so much. I also add out.height="50%", out.width="150%", but in this case, out.height option does not work. I am trying to make image fill the entire slide using both options but I cannot use both option effective? Can you give me a tip?

Comment: @joe, see my update.

Comment: thank you. I tried `{r, echo = FALSE, out.height="50%"}` but `out.height` option is not working. Why is it? Am I missing something here?

Comment: No, I am not sure why its not working, `out.height`, `out.width` should work.